# How to have screenreaders read something different from the text it contains?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

I have some text that is a number and a color. For instance, 2 (in red), or 3 (in green).  For blind users, I want to represent it as 2R or 3G, but everyone else should just see 2 or 3 in the color.

I tried the equivalent of `<span aria-label="2G">2</span>` but blind users report they only read the 2, and don't get the G. So they're confused because it's just a bunch of numbers and they have to guess the colors.

What can I do to make this work for blind users?

Comment: The `<span>` element will not report `aria-label` on its own. You can add `tabindex` to it, but please don't.

Comment: Oh, and colorblind users will struggle here (note that red-green colorblindness is more common than total blindness). And not everyone who uses a screen reader is blind, so that may confuse sighted screen reader users.

Answer (score 0):

What does the color represent?  If you have a label elsewhere on the page, you can give it an id and then use aria-labelledby with that id to have the screen reader say "2 car" and "3 truck" if red meant car and green meant truck.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-labelledby_attribute

You also have the option of adding "hidden" text by placing that text off the screen so that sighted users can't see it.  Basically you create a .hidden class in your stylesheet that positions that text off to the left, and just use that class for all of the screen reader-only text.  There's a good discussion of it over at http://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/.

Comment: Follow-up:  If you need to support right-to-left languages, you might need a more robust solution than putting the text off to the left, due to it creating scroll bars.  http://www.coolfields.co.uk/2016/05/text-for-screen-readers-only-updated/

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Of course, you could write "R" or "G" in transparent (`style="color: transparent"`). But this won't answer to people with color blindness who don't use screenreaders.

The best thing to do is just to write "Red" or "Green" in plain text. No 2, no 3, no R and no G which are meaningless and will never be accessible.